# How can I add the same note to several slides at once in Microsoft PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can I add the same note to several slides at once in Microsoft PowerPoint?

I tried to select several  slides and click on the note  panel, but doing so unselect all slides except the first one.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't want to use macro scripting, try copying and pasting the same note content, then selecting the next slide, and pasting again, until you have pasted the content on all the slides you want the notes on.
2. If it's just too many slides to do this, some macro scripting may need to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Would you know where I can find how to do the macro scripting for this? I have the same problem and I can't find a solution anywhere. Unfortunately my version of PowerPoint doesn't allow recording macros...

The closest solution I found was this, though it's a script for copying from a text file to the notes: https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00937_Importing_notes_text_from_a_text_file.htm

I don't know how to tweak it if I wanted the SAME note on ALL slides though

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1105462)